# moving down a navigation bar with "top: 0" by using only css

Tags: html, css

There is a navigation-bar with that css-definitions:

```
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 40px;
    ...
}

<div class="nav">...</div>
```

That means that this navigation is always on to of the page. But now I have to insert a second bar at the top of that naviation-bar.

```
.top-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 40px;
    ...
}

<div class="top-nav">...</div>
<div class="nav">...</div>
```

That "top-nav" will be displayed at several pages (i didn't know now). So I am not able to change the css definitions or the html of the class "nav".

I am looking only for a (css) possibility to move any html-tag with the css-attribut "top: 0" down for a fixed value.

JavaScript is not a solution: There several pages i will include that "top-nav".

Edit:

overlapping:

[image: overlapping]

not overlapping:

[image: not overlapping]

I am looking for that not overlapping solution.

Comment: can you make a screenshot of how you want and how it is being displayed now?

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your html if you want that a div reference to his container you have to put it inside the container. try this:

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="top-nav">...</div>
</div>
```

So the top-nav refers to the nav container.

**EDIT 1:**

No chance if you can't change the html. The thing you can do is add a javascript which add text inside top-nav. In this way you can generate code to put another div inside it.

for reference look at [jquery text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Thx. But i am not able the change the html of the page (so i am not able to insert the top-nav into the nav).

Comment: Why aren't you able to do that?

Comment: because I do not know on witch pages it will be included in future. So my there is no "top-nav" class to find it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
position: static;
```

or without position definition (static is the defaul). In static position each box appear in the order they are in the html.